# Probability question. red and blue T shirts

Tags: probability

A box contains 9 Red T shirts and 8 blue T shirts, it is known 1 Red T shirt and 2 blue T shirts are faulty.

A Red T shirts and a blue T shirts are selected at random. What is the probability that these are both in good condition?

The T shirts are then replaced and three Red T shirt and two blue T shirts are selected at random. What is the probability that these five items are in good condition?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: im ok with the first part, i think, as i get 2/3 chance they are in good condition but the 2nd part is completely confused me.

Comment: $\frac{2}{3}$ is correct for the first part.  For the second part... let us break down into smaller simpler steps.  Draw a single red shirt.  What is the chance that that single red shirt was in good condition?  Now, given that the first was in good condition, draw a second red shirt without having replaced the first and see if it is in good condition.  Then draw a third red shirt see if it is in good condition.  Apply rule of product to find the probability that all three of the red shirts were all in good condition.  Do the same for the blue shirts, and finally combine into a final answer

Comment: You could approach much more directly by using hypergeometric distributions, but given the way you presented your question it sounds as though you should be focusing on the fundamentals.

Comment: Very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: is 5/14 correct (0.35714)  I was stuck on not replacing and replacing the items during my calculations.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{8}{9}\times\frac{7}{8}\times\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{6}{8}\times\frac{5}{7}=\frac{5}{14}$ is correct, or as mentioned, written more directly as $\dfrac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{9}{3}}\times\dfrac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the T-shirts are then replaced?"